# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n\cdot\arccos{\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n\cdot\arccos{\dfrac{n^2}{n^2+1}}.$$

I have absolutely no ideas on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the half-angle formula for the tangent, we have
$$\arccos x = 2\arctan\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1 + x},\qquad -1 \lt x \leq 1. \tag1$$

Let $x = n^2 / (n^2 + 1)$. Since $n \to +\infty$, we have that $x \to 1$ (from below). Therefore we can directly apply $(1)$. After basic algebra, we get
$$L = \lim_{n \to +\infty} 2n\arctan\frac1{\sqrt{2n^2+1}}.$$

Using the fact that for $t \to 0$, $\arctan t = t + o(t^2)$, the limit finally simplifies to
$$L = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{2n}{\sqrt{2n^2 + 1}} = \sqrt 2.$$

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that arccos(x) is equivalent to $$\sqrt[]{2(1-x)}$$ when x->1

Comment: More exactly, since $x=\cos u=1-2\sin^2(u/2)$, $$\arccos(x)=u=2\arcsin(\sqrt{(1-x)/2})=\sqrt{2(1-x)}(1+O(|1-x|)).$$

Answer (score 1):

**Empirically**:

We would like to know the asymptotic behavior of

$$\arccos\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}\right)$$ for large $n$, i.e. for values of the argument close to $1$.

But the $\arccos$ function isn't well behaved in this area (the slope tends to infinity), so that we prefer to turn it to an $\arcsin$ using $\arccos(x)=\arcsin(\sqrt{1-x^2})$. This gives after simplification

$$\arccos\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}\right)=\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{2n^2+1}}{n^2+1}\right).$$

The argument of the arc sine can further be simplified as
$$\frac{\sqrt2}n,$$
and the arc sine is know to be the identity close to the origin, so that the requested limit is $$\sqrt2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using L'Hopital's rule:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\arccos\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\arccos\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}}{\frac{1}{n}}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}\right)^2}}\frac{(n^2+1)\cdot 2n-n^2\cdot 2n}{(n^2+1)^2}}{-\frac{1}{n^2}}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2n^3}{(n^2+1)\sqrt{(n^2+1)^2-n^4}}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2n^3}{(n^2+1)\sqrt{2n^2+1}}\\
&=\sqrt{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{4n^6}{(n^2+1)^2(2n^2+1)}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{4}{2}}=\sqrt 2.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to solve this problem is to use the substitute $x=\frac1n$. In fact,
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\arccos\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}&=&\lim_{x\to}\frac{1}{x}\arccos\frac{1}{1+x^2}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}\arctan \sqrt{(x^2+1)^2-1}\\
&=&\sqrt{2}.
\end{eqnarray}